# Save japanese characters in CSV file and zip and save it to specific location

Tags: c#, .net, csv, zip, file-handling

I want to save data, which is Japanese characters, in csv file. Then i want to zip the file and save it to a particular location.
Following is the code I am trying but it does not save the Japanese characters. 
Can any one please let me know the issue in the code. And please tell me how to zip it and save it to a location.

```
         var csvData = new StringBuilder();
         csvData.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",
            "申込区分", "オリジナルカード番号", "スペアカード番号", "セットＮＯ", "送り状番号",
            "入金", "カード発行", "キャンセル", "フォームID", "フォームID別のシーケンス番号", "ご希望のカード T-ポイント付きかどうか",
            "本人確認書類の種類", "本人確認書類の番号",
            "申込No", "申込日時", "エージェント名", "エージェントテーブルのID", "お名前（姓）", "お名前（名）", "ローマ字（姓）",
            "ローマ字（名）", "電話番号", "メールアドレス", "CCC専用会員ナンバー", "提携店会員ナンバー1", "提携店会員ナンバー2",
            "携帯番号", "生年月日", "職業", "性別", "母親の旧姓", "ご利用通貨", "初回チャージ額（ご入金予定額）", "カード種別コード",
            "通貨", "郵便番号", "都道府県", "都道府県ローマ字", "市郡区", "市郡区ローマ字", "町名", "町名ローマ字", "番地", "番地ローマ字",
            "建物名/階数/部屋番号など", "建物名/階数/部屋番号などローマ字", "ご出発予定日", "渡航国", "渡航（利用）目的",
            "渡航（利用）目的商品代金商品名", "渡航（利用）目的商品代金原産国", "渡航（利用）目的商品代金船積地", "渡航（利用）目的その他テキスト",
            "同意事項1", "同意事項2", "同意事項3", "同意事項4", "マイナンバー確認の有無", "マイナンバー確認日付", "マイナンバー不備",
            "本人確認書類不備",Environment.NewLine);



        var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.BufferOutput = true;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Employee.CSV ");
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        response.Write(csvData.ToString());
        response.End();
```

Comment: "but it does not save the Japanese characters." - What do you get instead?

Comment: I am getting following instead of japanese characters :

ç”³è¾¼åŒºåˆ† ã‚ªãƒªã‚¸ãƒŠãƒ«ã‚«ãƒ¼ãƒ‰ç•ªå· ã‚¹ãƒšã‚¢ã‚«ãƒ¼ãƒ‰ç•ªå· ã‚»ãƒƒãƒˆï¼®ï¼¯ é€ã‚ŠçŠ¶ç•ªå· å…¥é‡‘ ã‚«ãƒ¼ãƒ‰ç™ºè¡Œ

Comment: And did you check it is not simply an encoding issue of the viewer you are using to look at the result? Maybe it interpretes the data as utf 16 or something like that?

Comment: I am opening the file in Excel.

Comment: 1. Check if Excel expects the csv file to be in a certain encoding. (I believe you can make it use utf8.) 2. Check if you are using a unicode font that is able to display the respective code points.

Comment: Have you tried putting together a utf8-csv by hand and open that in excel? If you get the same result, the problem is not your code but excel.

Comment: I tried above, japanese characters are showing as question marks '????'. 
But in my case its not. It is coming as unreadable characters as shown above.

Comment: Try `response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`, see if it works.